# Setup static route to stay using the default gateway if there are 2 NIC & gateways in Windows 10 w/o fallback?

Tags: windows, windows-10, static-routes

Is there a way to setup static route on Windows 10 to restrict the PC to always use the gateway with the lowest metric as the default gateway, without falling back to the second gateway with a higher metric if the default gateway fails/timeouts?

Our network admin says that for Windows 7, the gateway in the lowest matric will usually be set as the default gateway without fallback to the second gateway.  This is the behavior he expects and he counts on that to keep the network secure.